# How to remove matching files but exclude some

Tags: shell, glob, rm

I have following files in current directory:

```
./
-- 1
-- a2
-- abca
-- abcb
-- abcc
-- abcd
-- abce
-- abcf
-- abcg
-- abch
-- test01
-- test02
-- test03
-- test04
-- test05
-- test06
-- test07
-- test08
-- test09
-- test10
```

I want to remove all `test*` file but exclude `test07` and `test09`.
How to accomplish this?

`rm test* !test07 !test09` doesn't work

Comment: `shopt -s extglob; rm test0+(1|2|3|4|5|6|8) test10` maybe?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name test\* ! -name test07 ! -name test09 -exec rm {} +` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`GLOBIGNORE="test0[79]"; rm test*` maybe?